# Asynchronous communication between ACL and BoundedContext

Tags: asynchronous, domain-driven-design, domain-events

We are following DDD for a  project... We need to access a legacy application from a bounded context . So we create an Anti corruption layer.. However we have a problem... The method that we are executing in the ACL is asynchronous and returns the result via an event... The result of call is used to update a db in the bound context...

In such scenarios  can we use Domain Events for communication between ACL and Bounded Context

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not? Even wrapped by an anticorruption layer it is a bounded context, and event exchange among BC looks pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a technical event than a domain event, but it is difficult to say from your description.

According to your description, **the event originates in the ACL, and not in the BC. This is a strong indication that it is not a domain event, because it has no meaning in your domain.**

Imagine a perfect world, where you wouldn't need the ACL. Would the event still exist?

Note that you can still use eventing to solve your technical problem though. It just isn't a domain event.